# Method stops in the middle of a method after an if-statement?

Tags: python, mongodb, discord.py

So, I wrote this method and I noticed that it was executing just fine, yet nothing was happening.

I added some debugging checks to figure out where the method started to fail, and it fails at the second if-statement.

```py
    @commands.command(aliases = ["send","give"])
    async def gift(self, ctx, Member: discord.Member, amount = None):
        await self.open_bank(ctx.author)
        await self.open_bank(member)
        ID = ctx.author.id
        MEM_ID = Member.id
        user = await collection.find_one({'_id': ID})
        print("check 1")
        if amount == None:
            await ctx.send("Please enter the amount")
            print("amount is None_type")
            return
        print("check 2")
        if amount > user['wallet']: # <-- problem starts here?
            await ctx.send("insufficient amount in your wallet")
            print("amount greater than wallet amount")
            return
        print("check 3")
        if amount < 0:
            await ctx.send("amount must be positive!")
            print("amount less than zero")
            return
        print("check 4")

        await collection.update_one({'_id': ID}, {'$set': {'wallet': -1*amount}})
        await collection.update_one({'_id': MEM_ID}, {'$set': {'wallet': amount}})

        await ctx.send(f"you sent {amount} coins to {Member.display_name}")
```

returns the results

`check 1
check 2`

as the debug results suggest, the method seems to be stopping after the second if statement.

Things I have tried:

- printing user['wallet'], which returns 178, my wallet balance.
- deleting the return statements.
- commenting out the `ctx.send()` lines
- setting an entire variable just for wallet with `user_wallet = user['wallet'] and referencing that instead.
- commented out the second if statement, which just stops the method after check 3 rather than check 2, but never reaches check 4.

edit: note, my wallet balance is 187. I'm doing `gift <user> 1`

Comment: So what's the issue? It seems to me that the second if statement is entered and returns from the function

Comment: the question is whether you understand what `return` does; in short it "stops" the function (at least if used alone or with `None` (which is basically the same))

Comment: According to your code, seems you want the program keep going after the `if` statement? You have tried deleting the `return` statements, doesn't that work for your purpose?

Comment: my balance is less than the amount. so the second if-statement shouldn't trigger

also, as mentioned I tried deleted all of the return statements.

Comment: Since the program prints "check 2", one of three things must follow: (1) it prints "check 3"; (2) it prints "amount greater than wallet amount"; (3) an exception is raised.  The list of things you tried did not include wrapping the code of this method inside a try:except:finally: block.   What happens when you do that?  This is a coroutine, and there are situations where exceptions raised in a coroutine might not result in a traceback unless you handle them explicitly.

Comment: Did you tried `print(user['wallet'])`  between `check2` and `if2`? If the return only `check1` and `check2`, I doubt `user['wallet']` working. Maybe it raised an exception.

Comment: ah. it raised an exception.
`'>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'`

Comment: thank you @PaulCornelius. how do I mark your answer as the solution? I'm new to stack overflow

Comment: For future reference, you can only mark an answer.  My post was only a comment.    I am glad you found your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Paul Cornelius for helping me with the solution.

> (1) it prints "check 3"; (2) it prints "amount greater than wallet amount"; (3) an exception is raised. The list of things you tried did not include wrapping the code of this method inside a try:except:finally: block.

After adding a try:except, the console returned `'>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'` indicating that I was passing in a string instead of an int. I fixed this by adding `amount = int(amount)` after the second if-statement.